# Prove that $E$ closure is closed

Tags: solution-verification

Always thank you for helping me out
I was following my professor's proof and this is how it goes

Prove that $E$ closure is closed
let $x$ be a limit point of $\operatorname{cl}(E)$, claim: $x$ is in $\operatorname{cl}(E)$
By the definition of a limit point, $(N_e(x)\setminus\{x\})\cap \operatorname{cl}(E)$ is nonempty, let $y$ be the element in $\operatorname{cl}(E) = E \cup E'$

1. $y$ is in $E$ $\implies$ $x$ is a limit point of $E$, then $x$ is in $E'$ thereby in $\operatorname{cl}(E)$ since $E'$ is a subset of $\operatorname{cl}(E)$
2. $y$ is in $E'$ $\implies$ $x$ is a limit point of $E'$ and $y$ is a limit point of $E$
   since $y$ is an interior point of $N_e(x)\setminus\{x\}$, there exists $z$ in $E_e'(y)\setminus\{y\}$ and $z$ is in $N_e(x)\setminus\{x\}$ $\implies$ $x$ is a limit point of $E$

I fully understood up to the first line of 2. where $y$ is a limit point of $E$, but how did he come up with the idea of $y$ is an interior point of $N_e(x)\setminus\{x\}$? Is it because a neighborhood is an open set, so any element in it should be an interior point?

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Usually closure means the smallest **closed** subset that contains $E$. What's your definition of closed?

Comment: I don't want to get into notational mess. Here is it in simple words: Let $x$ be a limit point of cl$(E)$ $\implies$ any open neighborhood $N$ of $x$ contains some point of cl$(E)$ call it $y$. Now $y$ can itself be a point of $E$ but if not then it must be a limit point of $E$. In that case every neighborhood of $y$ contains some point of $E$. Now $N$ is also an open neighborhood of $y$ so $N$ contains some point of $E$ and that's how you find $x$ in the closure of $E$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The closure of a set is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110424/the-closure-of-a-set-is-closed)

Comment: I am confused about your last sentence. y is in the neighborhood, every neighborhood of y contains some point of E, that point must be included in the previous neighborhood -> y is also a limit point of E. Am I understanding it correctly? Sorry, this is my first time trying the proof :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this proof is that it's a bit messy. I don't know what is $e$, what is $E_e'(y)$.

If I understand correctly, the definitions that are used are the following:

- $\bar E=E\cup E'$ where $E'=\{x:\forall (\varepsilon>0) N_\varepsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}\cap E\neq\emptyset\}$.
- $E$ is closed iff $E'\subset E$ (which is equivalent to: $\bar E=E$.

*Fact to prove:* $\bar E$ is closed.

*Proof.* We need to prove that $\bar E'\subset \bar E$. Take any $x\in\bar E'$. We are going to prove that $x\in E'\subset \bar E$. Take any $\varepsilon>0$. Our goal is to show that $N_\varepsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}\cap  E\neq\emptyset$. From the fact that $x\in \bar E'$ we have some $y\in N_\varepsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}\cap \bar E$. We see that $y\in E\cup E'$.

- If $y\in E$ then we are done.
- If $y\in E'$ then then there exists $z$ in a set $N_\delta(y)\setminus\{y\}\cap E$ for any $\delta>0$. Since $N_\varepsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}$ is open and $y$ belongs to it, we have $z\in N_\delta(y)\subset N_\varepsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}$ for some small $\delta$. Therefore $z\in N_\varepsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}\cap  E\neq\emptyset$.

[image: Two circles]

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for your kind explanation, Mateo. I went through the steps and fully understood the proof and the clarity of your proof (how it is written) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach, different than one from the lecture. In my opinion it's much simpler, but it needs some preparation, which is profitable and will pay off later.

*Fact (equivalent definitions of the closure)* The following statements are equivalent:

1. $x\in \bar E=E\cup E'$,
2. $N_\varepsilon(x)\cap E\neq\emptyset$ for all $\varepsilon>0$
3. $U\cap E\neq\emptyset$ for every $U$ - open neighbourhood of $x$.

*Proof*

$1.\implies 2.$: If $x\in E$ then $x\in N_\varepsilon(x)\cap E\neq\emptyset$. If $x\in E'$ then $$N_\varepsilon(x)\cap E \supset N_\varepsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}\cap E\neq\emptyset.$$

$2.\implies 1.$: If $x\in E$ then we are done. If not then
$$N_\varepsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}\cap E = 
N_\varepsilon(x)\cap E \neq\emptyset.$$ Therefore $x\in E'$.

$2.\implies 3.$: Take any $U$ as above. Therefore, since $U$ is open and $x\in U$, we have $N_\varepsilon(x)\subset U$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Therefore
$$ U\cap E\supset N_\varepsilon(x)\cap E\neq\emptyset.$$

$3.\implies 2.$: Obvious, since $N_\varepsilon(x)$ is an open nbhood of $x$. $\square$

---

Now we are ready  to show that $\bar E$ is closed, that is $\bar{\bar E}\subset \bar E$. We'll use the third condition.

*Proof* Take any $x\in \bar{\bar E}$. Take any open nbhood $U$ of $x$. Since $x\in \bar{\bar E}$, we have $y\in U\cap \bar E$. Since $y\in \bar E$ and $U$ is an open nbhood of $y$, we have $U\cap E\neq \emptyset$. This shows that $x\in\bar E$.

Comment: This one is harder..I will try to understand it