# Dumb question regarding the proof that the closure of a set is closed

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

For the purposes of this post, the closure $\text{cl}(A)$ of $A$ is defined as $A\cup A'$, where $A'$ is the derived set of $A$. I wish to show that $\text{cl}(A)$ is closed. Proofs of the statement are found all over the internet, for example, take Asinomás' proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2110429/362026). The standard proof goes as follows:

Let $x$ be a limit point of $\text{cl}(A)$. It is sufficient to show that any neighborhood $N$ of $x$ contains a point in $A$, so that $x$ is also a limit point of $A$ and thus $x\in A'\subseteq \text{cl}(A)$. Since $x$ is a limit point of $\text{cl}(A)=A\cup A'$, we must have either

1. $N$ contains a point $a\in A$, in which case we are done, or
2. $N$ contains a point $a'\in A'$, in which case ***it also contains a point $a\in A$***, and we are done.

---

In metric spaces, the statement in bold is easy to prove. In general topological spaces, I fail to see why it holds, and I was wondering if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Well, it all revolves around the definition of $A'.$ But the proof is pretty much the same, for some definition of neighborhood.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I still do not see it. In case 2), there is a neighborhood $N'$ of $a'$ that contains a point $a\in A$, but what guarantees that $a$ is contained in $N$? Why is it assumed we can force $N'$ to be a subset of $N$?

Comment: Since $a'\in N,$ $N$ is an open set (aka neighborhood) containing $a'.$ So...

Comment: How do you define "neighborhood" in a general topological space?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_neighbourhoods. Once they are defined as in the link (and open sets are defined) we may say $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ if and only if there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq N$. In a nutshell, neighborhoods need not be open.

Comment: But I may use $U$, since $U$ is a neighborhood of all its points (including $a'$), and thus contains a point $a\in A$ (due to $a'$ being a limit point of $A$). I see it now, thanks.